# How to use iOS's In-App purchase to buy user generated digital goods?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase

In my iOS app, photographers can upload photos and other people can buy a digital copy of the photo. After researching, I discovered that buyers must use [In-App Purchase](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/) rather than [Apple Pay](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/Getting-Started-with-Apple-Pay.pdf) because In-App Purchase is for digital goods, while Apple Pay is for physical goods.

I've run into a problem with using In-App Purchase to buy user generated content. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727-CH3-SW1) says:

> For each app, you can create **up to 1000 separate In-App Purchase**
> **products**. Every product you want to offer in your store must be
> configured in iTunes Connect.

1. My community of photographers will be creating more than 1000 photos.
2. I, the app developer, must go into the iTunes website to submit each individual product. This is not scalable for a user generated app.

[image]

The documentation of In-App Purchase makes it appear that I can only set up a small static list of products. If anyone has experience with letting users purchase over a thousand user-generated digital goods, please let me know.

## Possible Solution

I'm thinking about creating In-App items based off of a price tier:

- $1 Photo
- $5 Photo
- $10 Photo
- etc...

I'll only let my photographers sell photos within a static price tier. Does anyone know if creating items based on price, rather than what is actually being sold, will be approved by Apple?

Comment: This might be relevant. It is from the guidelines for app review. This is under things that will get your app rejected: 11.3 Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used outside of the App will be rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting question! In my opinion, you should go more with physical-style purchases. Why? In-app purchases are designed for buying functionality of an app and ready packages, but not particular photos. The good solution for this will be to sell "bundles" or create an in-app currency. For example, you can sell bundle of 10 photos and user can spend them on photos. But no tiering here.
If you decide to create an in-app currency, e.g. points, you can sell point bundles  for some money (e.g. $10 = 100 points, $50 = 700 points) and then let users set the price for their photos. It is pretty obvious, that you can take some extra from each purchase of the photo or when user decides to withdraw in-app currency to real money.
This technique already works in games and in this dating app: https://coffeemeetsbagel.com
The only thing you should care  is the implementation of in-app currency "buyback". As far, as I know, there is no way to sell it to Apple again, so you need to set up custom backend for the billing.
If you go with your idea, you can use the same approach, as I described, but instead of currency, users will buy tiers. And then spend "one $10 photo coin" on one photo. But the idea of currency is better as for me.